# Problems in testing telnet using postfix

Tags: postfix, telnet

i am quite new so please be a bit patient XD
i am trying to configure a mail server using postfix (which implements a database for aliases, domains and mailboxes) and courrier on ubuntu. I have this problem when i test the command telnet:
451 4.3.0 : Temporary lookup failure
I followed this guide: http://guide.debianizzati.org/index.php/Postfix-mysql#Postfix

Do you know how can i solve this problem? Tell me which log and configuration file do you needn to know. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Send a test email through telnet? The syntax is "telnet $host $port" and in your case, "telnet localhost 25" if you've got postfix configured correctly as your default MTA and it is working correctly.

Comment: yes i am trying to send a test mail but it doesnt seem to be correct and i dont know why. the process is listening but when i try 
mail from: 
and mail to: i receveid that error.